# How do I use multithreading in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need to know how can I make an unknown number of threads from a number, here is my code:

```
void callWritePrimesMultipleThreads(int begin, int end, string filePath, int N){
  ofstream file;
  file.open(filePath);
  thread myThreads[N];//cant make it because N isnt a constant value.
}
```

I really thought about making an array but I can't because the number I receive is unknown for the function, is there any way to multiply threads in this function?

Comment: Did you think about `std::vector<std::thread> myThreads (N);`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius like this: vector<thread> myThreads(N);?

Comment: Too hard, too much for a beginner. First, try something like "making a number of `int`s from unknown number".

Comment: @SimpleNigal Updated my comment.

Comment: If you are struggling with this, stay away from threads until this sort of question is trivial.  Threads add a huge amount of complexity to a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `std::vector` in your function:

```
void callWritePrimesMultipleThreads(int begin, int end, string filePath, int N){
  ofstream file;
  file.open(filePath);
  vector<std::thread> myThreads;
}
```

Then add the threads to the vector using `push_back(thread t)`, like this:   `myThreads.push_back(thread)`, however if this question is difficult to you it might be a good idea to stay away from threads for a while, as they complicate a program very much.

Comment: @SimpleNigal Could you please upvote the answer too, as you accepted it?